# How to Django + Haystack + multisite?

Tags: django-haystack

What's the correct/best way to configure django-haystack for a multisite?

Currently everything works but results are not restricted to the current site.

Answer (score 2):

**indexes.py**

```
from haystack.indexes import SearchIndex, IntegerField

class SiteSearchIndex(SearchIndex):
    site_id = IntegerField(model_attr="site__id")
```

My search_indexes inherit from that class.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import search_view_factory
from myapp.apps.search.views import SearchView

sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(site_id=settings.SITE_ID).order_by("-pub_date")
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^$",
        search_view_factory(
            view_class=SearchView, searchqueryset=sqs, form_class=SearchForm
        ),
        name="search-index"
    ),
)
```